# Calculating mean of column in dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, 'A' and 'B', both consisting of values between 0 and 1.

How do I, for example, calculate the mean of the values in column 'B' when the value in column 'A' is between 0 and 0.1, ignoring the other values?

Comment: df.loc[df.B.between(0,0.1),'A'].mean()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['A'].between(0,0.1), 'B'].mean()
```

Or in this case, since the values are already `>=0`, you can just do:

```
df.loc[df['A'].le(0.1), 'B'].mean()
```